# weird text concatenation

Tags: python, text

I get weird output when I concatenate.
When it use this:

```
print 'sadasdadgdsfdajfhdsgsdkjhgsfjhdfdsfds'+'.323232600656520346403'
```

it works fine.

but when i do this:

```
getReference = open('test.txt','r')

for line in getReference:#os.path.exists(''+line+'.txt')

    try:
        with open(''+line+'.txt') as f: pass
    except IOError as e:
        newURL ='http://www.intrat.th/'+''.join(line)+'.fsta'
        print newURL
```

When I print newURL it doesn't give me one line text but instead it has .fsta on the second line.
why is this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your line:

```
for line in getReference:
```

will iterate over lines in the file, including the newline character(s) \n (and \r).
Therefore, you are probably trying to open a file 'filename\n.txt', which is not what you mean to do.

As as solution, use strip:

```
with open(''+line.strip()+'.txt') as f: pass
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `line` is terminated with a `'\n'`, a newline character.

One way of fixing this is:

```
for line in getReference:
    line = line.strip()
    # more code manipulating line
    # print stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're reading in the newline character. Try the following:

```
getReference = open('test.txt','r')

for line in getReference:#os.path.exists(''+line+'.txt')
    line = line.rstrip('\n') # Strip the newline here

    try:
        with open(''+line+'.txt') as f: pass
    except IOError as e:
        newURL ='http://www.intrat.th/'+''.join(line)+'.fsta'
        print newURL
```

Note that the newline separator may not be correct for your OS, in which case you can do

```
import os
# all your code
line = line.rstrip(os.linesep)
# more code
```